# Pass filehandle and read from in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to open a file and pass it to a function and read in 100 line chunks.
To do this I did:

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Unable to open the file: $!";
#get the header out
my $header = <$fh>;
my @columns =  get_column_headers($header);
getData($fh, 100);

...

sub getData {
  my $fh = shift;
  my $maxLines = shift;
  my $count = 0;
  while (my $line = <$fh> && $count < $maxLines) {
        print "line is : $line \n"; 
  }
}
```

This prints line is : 1
If I do a print ref on $fh after open and when I pass it to getData it prints out GLOB. How do I actually retrieve the remaining lines instead of "1" which I assume is the number of lines it read? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a precedence issue.

```
my $line = <$fh> && $count < $maxLines
```

means

```
my $line = ( <$fh> && $count < $maxLines )
```

so add parens

```
( my $line = <$fh> ) && $count < $maxLines
```

---

Oh, and you forgot to increment `$count`.

```
( my $line = <$fh> ) && ++$count <= $maxLines
```

Comment: Thanks this was driving me mad for the past couple hours.

Comment: Wasn't the `and` operator added exactly to solve this precendence problem of Perl? That would be a more intuitive solution to this.

Comment: @sundar, Not quite. It's usually used in flow control (`and next`, `and die`, etc), and `&&` is usually used in conditions. You could use `and` here, but I wouldn't call it intuitive. In fact, it was exactly the opposite of intuitive since it didn't occurred to me at all to use it there.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity

`(my $line = <$fh> && $count < $maxLines)` is being interpretted as `(my $line = (<$fh> && $count < $maxLines))`, returning a true value (1) to $line.

it is better written as  `(my $line = <$fh> and $count < $maxLines)` or `((my $line = <$fh>) && ($count < $maxLines))`.